# How to calculate the area of each region from an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwikI.png)

I want to calculate the areas of the individual regions surrounded by the white boundaries in the image. I tried the matlab code below, but the results are inaccurate:

```
a = rgb2gray(imread("flox2 (1).tif"));
figure,imshow(a)

thresholdValue = 100;
binaryImage = a > thresholdValue;
props = regionprops(binaryImage, 'all');
numberOfBlobs = numel(props);
boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
numberOfBoundaries = size(boundaries, 1);
hold on; % Don't let boundaries blow away the displayed image.
for k = 1 : numberOfBoundaries
    thisBoundary = boundaries{k}; % Get boundary for this specific blob.
    x = thisBoundary(:,2); % Column 2 is the columns, which is x.
    y = thisBoundary(:,1); % Column 1 is the rows, which is x.
    plot(x, y, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 2); % Plot boundary in red.
end
hold off;
for k = 1 : numberOfBlobs           % Loop through all blobs.
    % Find the individual measurements of each blob.  They are field of each structure in the props strucutre array.
    % You could use the bracket trick (like with blobECD above) OR you can get the value from the field of this particular structure.
    % I'm showing you both ways and you can use the way you like best.
    %meanGL = props(k).MeanIntensity;       % Get average intensity.
    blobArea = props(k).Area;               % Get area.
    %blobPerimeter = props(k).Perimeter;        % Get perimeter.
    %blobCentroid = props(k).Centroid;      % Get centroid one at a time
    % Now do the printing of this blob's measurements to the command window.
    fprintf(1,'#%2d %17.1f %11.1f %8.1f %8.1f %8.1f % 8.1f\n', k,  blobArea);
end
```

The image below shows the result after implementing the code. There are small regions surrounded by the red boundaries which shouldn't be there. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[Image after implementing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS95E.png)

Comment: This is far from trivial, you cannot segment those cells with just a threshold. There is a lot of literature on this topic, I suggest you look there first, try to replicate those methods.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo,

Is it possible to do manual segmentation?

Comment: Do you mean manually draw the outline of the regions you want to measure? Sure,  you can do that.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo,

Yes. I wanted to do that. Could you give some idea on how to do that?

Comment: @farabee [This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/roi-creation-overview.html) looks promising.

Comment: To farabee: cell segmentation solutions https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/74200-cell-segmentation-rfove-method?s_tid=srchtitle_cell%20segmentation_2

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67313-cell-segmentation-seg-self-method?s_tid=srchtitle_cell%2520segmentation_3

Comment: cell detection : https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/detecting-a-cell-using-image-segmentation.html?searchHighlight=cell%20segmentation&s_tid=srchtitle_cell%2520segmentation_4